# com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'q'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to learn how to work with a database in Java using MySql. I'm having this error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'q'

which means I'm having type mismatch but I can't figure out why. Here is my code. I have included ResultSetMetaData to show the datatypes of columns.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Prep {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    try {

        Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);

        PreparedStatement pstmt=c.prepareStatement("update emp2211 set name=? where id=?");

        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery("Select * from emp2211");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd= rs.getMetaData();  

        System.out.println("Total columns: "+rsmd.getColumnCount());  
        System.out.println("Column Name of 1st column: "+rsmd.getColumnName(1));  
        System.out.println("Column Type Name of 1st column: "+rsmd.getColumnTypeName(1));
        System.out.println("Column Name of 2nd column: "+rsmd.getColumnName(2));  
        System.out.println("Column Type Name of 2nd column: "+rsmd.getColumnTypeName(2));

        pstmt.setInt(1, 800);
        pstmt.setString(2, "q");

        pstmt.executeUpdate();

        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        }
        pstmt.close();
        c.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {         
        System.out.println(e);
    }


}
}
```

This is my output

```
Total columns: 2
Column Name of 1st column: id
Column Type Name of 1st column: INT
Column Name of 2nd column: name
Column Type Name of 2nd column: VARCHAR
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'q'
```

Comment: You should *not* reuse a `PreparedStatement` as a regular `Statement`. Create a separate `Statement` object for the `executeQuery("...")` call.

Comment: `Statement s = c.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("Select * from emp2211");`
like this? do I have to create `Statement` object every time I need to call `executeQuery`?

Comment: No, but calling `executeQuery` will close any previous `ResultSet` on the same [`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) object. From javadoc: *By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. [...] **All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statement's current ResultSet object if an open one exists**.* So I was surprised to see that `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()` didn't do that. Could be driver dependent.

Comment: You're right. `executeQuery` do close any previous `ResultSet`. I used `ResultSet` before the `executeUpdate` to use the `ResultSetMetaData` so that I could figure out where I'm going wrong. My bad.

Comment: The MySQL Connector/J should follow the JDBC specification and throw an `SQLException` on calling `executeQuery(String)` on a `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting a `String` to an numeric column.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt=c.prepareStatement("update emp2211 set name=? where id=?");
...
pstmt.setInt(1, 800);       
pstmt.setString(2, "q");    // the second ? is referred to id
```

Probably you need to the following?

```
PreparedStatement pstmt=c.prepareStatement("update emp2211 set name=? where id=?");
...
pstmt.setString(1, "q");       
pstmt.setInt(2, 800);
```

Comment: Thanks for notifying me of that.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
  import java.sql.*;

public class Prep {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    try {

        Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);

        PreparedStatement pstmt=c.prepareStatement("update emp2211 set name=? where id=?");

        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery("Select * from emp2211");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd= rs.getMetaData();  

        System.out.println("Total columns: "+rsmd.getColumnCount());  
        System.out.println("Column Name of 1st column: "+rsmd.getColumnName(1));  
        System.out.println("Column Type Name of 1st column: "+rsmd.getColumnTypeName(1));
        System.out.println("Column Name of 2nd column: "+rsmd.getColumnName(2));  
        System.out.println("Column Type Name of 2nd column: "+rsmd.getColumnTypeName(2));

        //this is your error
        pstmt.setString(1, "q");
        pstmt.setInt(2, 800);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        }
        pstmt.close();
        c.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {         
        System.out.println(e);
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Explanation would clarify answer.

Comment: parameterIndex - the first parameter is 1, the second is 2, .like this ex:PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEES
                                     SET SALARY = ? WHERE ID = ?");
   pstmt.setBigDecimal(1, 153833.00)
   pstmt.setInt(2, 110592)

Comment: This was aa great help.

Answer (score -1):

simply follow correct order as input

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).